# hair particles are not scaling correctly with object

Tags: particles, hair

[image]

i have tried applying scale, scaling object in edit mode, deleting particle system and creating new. the scale always come out too large

Comment: Why look the particles like this? Are they particles rendered as object or are there object with a Particle Instance modifier?

Comment: @Blunder I think it’s because it is short, tremendously fat hair. They are triangular and flat, but they look rounded.

Comment: ya its just hair that is very off scale

Comment: Wow, they look like under a microscope. Have you tried to lower the values for *Hair Shape > Diameter Root* and *Tip*?